# Receiving Error 1822 - After attempting to add GuestNames as a foreign key in MealPreferences table

Tags: sql, mysql

I am using MySQL Workbench. I receive the following error: Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'mealpreferences_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'seatingchart'

Can you please give me a hand in understanding why this is happening?

Here is my SQL:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS WEDDINGPLANNING;

CREATE DATABASE WEDDINGPLANNING;

USE WEDDINGPLANNING;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VendorInformation (
VendorName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
VendorType varchar(50) NOT NULL,
ContactPerson varchar(100) NOT NULL,
ContactNumber varchar(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (VendorName)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SeatingChart (
TableName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
GuestNames varchar(100) NOT NULL,
MaxCapacity int NOT NULL,
Location varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Location)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WeddingInformation (
CoupleName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
WeddingDate date NOT NULL,
Venue varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CoupleName, Venue)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Vendor_Wedding (
VendorName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
CoupleName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (VendorName, CoupleName),
FOREIGN KEY (CoupleName) REFERENCES WeddingInformation (CoupleName) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (VendorName) REFERENCES VendorInformation (VendorName) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MusicPreferences (
CoupleName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
SongName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Artist varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Genre varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CoupleName, SongName),
FOREIGN KEY (CoupleName) REFERENCES WeddingInformation (CoupleName) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MealPreferences (
CoupleName varchar (100) NOT NULL,
GuestNames varchar(100) NOT NULL,
MealChoice varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (GuestNames),
FOREIGN KEY (CoupleName) REFERENCES WeddingInformation (CoupleName) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (GuestNames) REFERENCES SeatingChart (GuestNames) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);`
```

I've tried swapping the CREATE TABLE statements and adding the foreign key of GuestNames to SeatingChart instead. I've tried asking ChatGPT for advise which told me that Location, Guestnames has been made a composite key. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Looks like you're missing an index on `SeatingChart`.`GuestNames`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html is a good read

Comment: 'Can you please give me a hand in understanding why this is happening?' - error is telling you why..consider adding names to FKs to narrow it down.

Comment: Every foreign key must reference a column (or columns) that are indexed.  Apart from the last foreign key you've defined, all the others are referencing columns that are included in primary keys.  However, on the MealPreferences table, you're trying to set up a foreign key to the SeatingChart.GuestNames column, but this isn't part of a primary key or an index.  Add `INDEX (GuestNames)` to your `SeatingChart` table definition and see if that fixes things?

Comment: You should rethink your FKs anyway. A foreign key should only reference column sets that are unique in the referenced table. Ideally the primary key.

Comment: Thank you! I rethought my FKs and have resolved the issue. Also read the document provided. New to SQL, thanks for the help!